# PySpark job hangs forever (during real-time analysis)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

A week ago I posted a similar question but it never got answered.
I have spent a lot of time debugging the issue I'm having, allow me to briefly introduce the problem:

After about 8 - 16 hours (11 hours on average), there is one job that gets stuck and Spark stalls. Screenshots

[image]

and

[image]

If I manually (kill) that job, then Spark crashes.

The log4j logs don't show any warnings/errors at all. So I added my own logger to find at which step it fails. My code looks like this:

```
DS = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ...)
dstream = DS.map(...)
dstream.foreachRDD(lambda time, rdd:
    rdd.foreachPartition(lamda parti: doWork(time, parti) )
)

def doWork(time, parti):
    for part in parti:
            mention = part['mention'] # extract string from json
            words = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(mention)
            kw = part['keyword']
            #...
            log.info("I")
            if len(set(dictKeywords[kw]).intersection([w.lower() for w in words])) <= 0:
                    retobj['keeper']=0 # don't keep it
            elif detect(editedMention) != 'en':
                    retobj['keeper']=0 # don't keep it

            cleantxt = ppr.clean(mention)
            log.info("J")
            # ...
```

Here is the log file as of when the job got stuck:

```
...
2018-01-16 16:48:35,797 I
2018-01-16 16:48:35,818 J
...
2018-01-16 16:48:35,853 I

^ this is the end (job got stuck after printing "I")
```

It should print "J", but it doesn't, so one of three functions is causing it to hang/crash/stall: set.Intersect / langdetect.detect / tweet-preprocessor ppr.

But it doesn't make sense, why does it fail after so much time? I have "try + except" blocks everywhere in my code, and if there was an exception it would've been logged.

- I am on local mode (single node).
- I use "spark-submit" to launch the python script.
- I have tried making Spark use both Python 3.5.2 and Python 3.6 .
- I have tried with caching RDDs and without caching.
- It's not an OOM issue, the GC logs didn't indicate anything unusual.

Any ideas? Thanks!!!

Comment: `local` mode is a development tool. It is not designed for long term production use.

Comment: Your log output seems strange.  The first three lines are `HIJ`, but your code says that `I` should be followed by `N`.

Comment: That's what I also thought about, so I think I should make it run in standalone and see if the same thing happens. Thanks for your quick reply. But even though it's development mode, why does it behave so strange? Sometimes it runs of 20+ hrs but eventually crashes, and sometimes it crashes after 1hr.

@JohnGordon, I have edited the log output because the real log contains more letters -- I edited my post above to make it match the code.

Comment: It is, but in `local` mode there is a lot of stuff squeezed into a single JVM. UI output alone can consume a lot of resources. But TBH your guess is a good as mine at the moment. Have you seen anything unusual when you monitor memory usage in general? How about the input? Is it possible that there is some large spike in Kafka which overwhelms PySpark executor?

Comment: Not at all. It might have been the webUI. I also tried increasing driver/executor memory to 1, 2 and 4gb. I am currently setting it up to run in standalone mode, maybe that's the trick :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you wouldn't hold my breath here. Unless you can provide a bit more context, I doubt anyone will be able to help you without more details. One thing you can try is increasing cores and enabling speculative execution (`spark.speculation`).

Comment: Well if I had more details I would give them. However, my code is very trivial, and yet it fails still. I'll see whether standalone mode does the trick, if not, I'll see what else I can provide :) thanks!

Comment: With this behavior it is also possible that something specific to the input trips `nltk`. You can try logging the offset and trying if the problem can be reproduced outside Spark for this message.

Comment: Yes that is very possible. However, I have several Kafka producers (scripts) which also use "nltk" without any problem(s). If the "standalone" mode (which is currently running) will crash, then I'll investigate those modules outside of spark thoroughly. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

@user8371915 I would like to thank you very much for helping me out.
I believe I have identified the problem and running  a final test now.

The Tweet-Preprocessor module which I use (source: https://github.com/s/preprocessor ) has a very nasty bug. Have a look at this code:

```
import preprocessor as ppr
mention = "Try this Bitcoin Price app https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/bitcoin-price-calculator/id1315298877?mt=8[app](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/bitcoin-price-calculator/id1315298877?mt=8)"
print(mention)
cleantxt = ppr.clean(mention)
print(cleantxt)
```

The code above will get stuck forever in the "clean" method. But this only happens for a very specific tweet (like the one above). So it takes several hours until such a tweet is encountered.

I have removed everything related to the preprocessor module and re-designed my code. I believe I will no longer have this problem again.